# Jmeter tool, thread loop count is forever and number of threads 1 skips html pages in loop controller in incremental way

Tags: jmeter

Thread group properties: 1 thread, loop count forever. In recorded script there is run time controller, which has child Loop controller, which further has 4 child HTML pages.

When test is executed, it executes all HTML pages in order which are outside runtime controller, and the pages inside it are executed one by one eg. 1.html, then in next loop it will skip 1,3,4 and execute 2, in next iteration it will execute 3 an skip rest. Why is this happening?

Comment: can you add your test plan image (screenshot), please?

Comment: Sorry, can't upload screenshots, this is against firms policies.

Comment: see my answer, hope this helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, @bg Fan -- test continues running (though loops count are ended) -- because of parameter `Runtime (seconds)` in `Runtime Controller`. If you need its several time execution (so if test duration measures by execution counts,**not by time** in sec., etc.) -- not place all requests in parent `Runtime Controller`, disable/delete it. 
Worked for me.

Comment: Thanks! reducing runtime controllers time helped. It was 3600 initially, changing it to 40 solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

@bg Fan, i've reproduced your words (say, if wrong) and now i have this test behaviour:

[image]
This correlates with [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller)

> If you add Generative or Logic Controllers to a Loop Controller, JMeter will loop through them a certain number of times, in addition to the loop value you specified for the Thread Group. For example, if you add one HTTP Request to a Loop Controller with a loop count of two, and configure the Thread Group loop count to three, JMeter will send a total of 2 * 3 = 6 HTTP Requests.

Can i help you with anything else?

Comment: Loop controller iterates forever even though thread groups loop count is 1 and Loop controllers loop count is 1. it goes in to infinite loop.